# Delete files whose filename starts with a certain number

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-io

I'm trying to delete all files in a folder which start with a specific user id so if the user id = `00000` then I want to delete file `00000-1.xml` & `00000-2.xml` & `00000-3.xml` and so on.

I have this code so far:

```
    Dim path as String = Server.MapPath("../myfolder/xml/00000" & something?? & ".xml")

    If path <> "" Then
        Dim fileInfo As FileInfo = Nothing
        Try
            fileInfo = New FileInfo(path)
            If fileInfo.Exists Then
                File.Delete(path)
            End If
        Catch
        End Try

    End If
```

Obviously I have just added the `something??` in as i have no idea what to put there?

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) instead.

```
Dim path as String = Server.MapPath("../myfolder/xml")
If path <> "" Then
    Dim fileName As String
    For Each fileName in Directory.GetFiles (path, "00000-*.xml")
            File.Delete(fileName)
    Next

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just enumerate through any files, if they exist like this (will need to convert to VB syntax):

```
foreach (string DeleteFileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath(@"../MyFolder/xml"), "00000*.xml"))
{
    File.Delete(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"../MyFolder/xml"), DeleteFileName));
}
```

Note, I don't recall offhand whether EnumberateFiles gives just the file name or the fullpath.  if fullpath, you can drop the Path.Combine().

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath(@"../myfolder/xml", "0000*.abc")).ToList().ForEach(File.Delete);
```